# HTTP Status 415 - RESTEASY001055: Cannot consume content type

Tags: java, rest

I'm trying to upload an image (eg tiff, scan in PDF). I did a project in SoapUI and the picture was sent correctly, unfortunately my java code is wrong ... receives the '*HTTP Status 415 - RESTEASY001055: Cannot consume content type*' message. The image is stored in the database as a blob.
For code 200, I should get json

```
private void sendRequestToRestService(byte[] imgageBlob) throws IOException {
String user = "testUser";
String password = "testPass";
String restServiceAddressToUpload = //The address of the service on which I want to send the file;
String authData = user + ":" + password;
Tika tika = new Tika();
String mimetype = tika.detect(imgageBlob);

String auth = user + ":" + password;
byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));
String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);

//  ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(imgageBlob);

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Response res = client.target(restServiceAddressToUpload)
        .request(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader)
        .post(Entity.entity(imgageBlob, mimetype));

if (res.getStatus() == 200) {
    String readEntity = res.readEntity(String.class);
    // ...
} else {
    String readEntity = res.readEntity(String.class);
    // ...
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `Content-Type` header

Comment: ....header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader).header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)...?

Comment: Try `application/octet-stream`

Comment: so, yes? ....header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader).header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)... ?

Comment: Thanks. I do not have access to the test environment now. I'll check in a few hours.